# how to allow paging operation to navigate from one page to another in grid view control

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, datagridview

I am trying to navigate from 1 page to another in `gridview` control. When I attempt getting error

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0123: No overload for 'GridView1_PageIndexChanging'  
matches delegate 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewSelectEventHandler'
```

My ASPX page:

```
<pagersettings mode="Numeric"  position="Bottom"  pagebuttoncount="10"/>

<pagerstyle backcolor="LightBlue" height="30px" verticalalign="Bottom"   horizontalalign="Center"/>

</asp:GridView>
```

My code in C#:

```
 protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Please help me out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally before binding the data on the paging event you must bind it to a datasource.

Here is the sample. I use view state to store the datatable values which i retrieve on my page load event. Hope this helps

```
 private void gridview1_PageIndexChanging(object sender,System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs e)        
 {
    gridview1.ShowFooter = false;
    gridview1.EditIndex = -1;
    gridview1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        if (ViewState("VW_Data") != null) {
            dtData= new DataTable();
            dtData= (DataTable)ViewState("VW_Data");

            gridview1.DataSource = dtData;
            gridview1.PageSize = ddlRecordsPerPage.SelectedValue;
            gridview1.DataBind();
        } 
       else {
               GetData();
            }
  }
```